# What's wrong with Greenland and Africa?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What's wrong with Greenland and Africa?

I'm not sure if I'm missing some historical facts here regarding the borders of **Greenland** (or <del>all</del> most of **African countries** for that matter), but **after hiding the Water feature styles**, a large number of countries look like **random polygons**.

See example here: https://thenomadicyear.com/

Anyone having an idea about why this is happening? Could this be an API glitch?

Using Google Maps JavaScript API 3.

Styles used:

```
styles.minimal = [
    { //hide all fills
        elementType: 'geometry.fill',
        stylers: [
            { "visibility": 'off' }
        ]
    },
    {
        featureType: 'landscape.natural.landcover',
        elementType: 'geometry.fill',
        stylers: [
            { "visibility": 'on' },
            { "color": '#f2f2f2' },
            // { "lightness": 45 }
        ]
    },
    /*{
     "featureType": "landscape",
     "elementType": "all",
     "stylers": [
     { "color": '#f2f2f2' }
     ]
     },
     {
     featureType: "landscape",
     elementType: "geometry",
     stylers: [
     { "color": '#f2f2f2' }
     ]
     },*/
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            // { "color": "#333333" }
            // , { "visibility": "simplified" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#333333" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            // { "visibility": "off" }
            // { "saturation": -100 },
            // { "lightness": 45 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
            // { "visibility": "simplified" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: There is an open issue in the issue tracker on that: [Issue 6217: Bug: Basic Layerstyle option create artefact for Africa and Groenland](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6217)

Comment: Oh! I've been looking for an answer for this for so long. Thank you!

Comment: "Star" [that issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6217) if you are interested in seeing it fixed (it currently only has 6 people that have indicated interest)

Comment: Yup, already did that. It's just that it took me 5 minutes to find the darn star.